# Angular unit test for custom component text input value

Tags: angular, unit-testing, queryselector

What is the correct selector for nativeElement.querySelector to get the `value` of a `<input type=text>` in a unit test?

For an Angular app I have a custom read-only text box with the selector `app-read-only-textbox` and the markup as below

```
<div class="form-group mt-2 mb-2">
  <label for="read-only-text-box" class="label-text-size">{{ labelText }}</label>
  <input type="text" id="read-only-text-box" class="form-control" readonly [value]=textValue>
</div>
```

and the `labelText` and `textValue` properties declared as input variables:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-read-only-textbox',
  templateUrl: './read-only-textbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./read-only-textbox.component.scss']
})
export class ReadOnlyTextboxComponent{
  @Input() labelText = 'Default label text';
  @Input() textValue = '';
}
```

When unit testing if I use the `nativeElement.querySelector('input')` I get an input with no `value` property eg

```
<input _ngcontent-a-c64="" type="text" id="read-only-text-box" readonly="" class="form-control">
```

if I use `nativeElement.querySelector('app-read-only-textbox')` I get the whole component which contains the textbox value I'm looking for eg. in the `ng-reflect-label-text` property.

```
<app-read-only-textbox labeltext="Read-only label text" _nghost-a-c64="" ng-reflect-label-text="Read-only label text" ng-reflect-text-value="Some text value"><div _ngcontent-a-c64="" class="form-group mt-2 mb-2"><label _ngcontent-a-c64="" for="read-only-text-box" class="label-text-size">Read-only label text</label><input _ngcontent-a-c64="" type="text" id="read-only-text-box" readonly="" class="form-control"></div></app-read-only-textbox>
```

What can I specify in the `querySelector` to grab the text value for the input? Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?